# Android - View from next activity is showing up too early

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I have a button that when pressed changes MainActivity to CameraActivity that contains a camera preview and a progress bar. However, right before the activity switches the progress bar appears, so you end up seeing the progress bar on MainActivity for a split second. What could be causing this? Thanks

Here's some relevant code.

MainActivity.java

```
public void openCamera(View view) {
    if (getCameraInstance() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(FeedActivity.this, "Camera is unavailable right now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

CameraActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 0, 100);
    animation.setDuration(10000);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, currentCameraId);
    preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);


}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answer - [Is there any way to listen for when the camera has loaded in? cwac-camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189885/is-there-any-way-to-listen-for-when-the-camera-has-loaded-in-cwac-camera/).

Camera is loading slower than standard View, so my proposition is to create loading view ( create some ViewGroup in Your layout specially for this ) and it should be visible by default ( such loading view is more user frendly when camera loads to long), progressbar should be hided on default, next when camera is ready ( check linked question ) show progressbar and hide loading view.

Some code

```
mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // camera is "loaded" 
        //show progressbar
        //hide loading screen
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to use the link you posted though. Do I make a new class that includes that, and call that instead new CameraPreview? Also, is there anything I can do to optimize the camera loading speed so I don't have to have an intermediate preview (or the loading preview).

Comment: try use callback mCamera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(previewCallback); in previewCallback show progressbar

Comment: Should I place that right after mCamera = getCameraInstance()?

Comment: Yes it can be there but, remember that progress must be hided and showed in onPreviewFrame method.

Comment: i added that in right after getCameraInstance(), and it doesn't trigger

Comment: Got it figured out. Thanks